# Syntax Error with Foreign Key in `` Quotes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Need your small help here, I was trying to do a join which is showing syntax Error.

syntaxError: invalid syntax

```
df_results = df_tempTable2.join(df_parent, df_tempTable2.`entity_key|inv.entity|entity_id|entity_key|FK` == df_parent.enterprise_id,"inner")
```

Not sure how to use FK with ``, or how, as this might be the cause here- `df_tempTable2.entity_key|inv.entity|entity_id|entity_key|FK`

where as `entity_key|inv.entity|entity_id|entity_key|FK` is a Foreign Key.

Comment: If `entity_key|inv.entity|entity_id|entity_key|FK` is the name of your column, then instead of `df_tempTable2.\`entity_key|inv.entity|entity_id|entity_key|FK\`` use `F.col('entity_key|inv.entity|entity_id|entity_key|FK')`

Comment: @ZygD that Doesn't work, let me know if its wrong-  df_tempTable2.col('entity_key|inv.entity|entity_id|entity_key|FK')

Comment: It's wrong - read carefully what I have written before. Do the exact replace

Comment: You should also use this import: `from pyspark.sql import functions as F`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked-

```
df_tempTable2.join(df_parent, on = [df_tempTable2["`entity_key|inv.entity|entity_id|entity_key|FK`"] == df_parent["enterprise_id"]], how = "inner")
```